# Trouble writing my notation for natural numbers in Coq

Tags: coq

Why does Coq not accept this?

```
Notation "[ d1 , .. , d2 ]" := (addition (multiply ( .. d1 .. ) ten) d2).
```

Comment: Could you explain what it should mean? Looking at the code I cannot guess what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Recursive notations](http://coq.inria.fr/doc/Reference-Manual015.html#RecursiveNotations) need to obey fairly strict rules. The pattern to repeat must appear twice (that's how Coq knows what is to be repeated): once using `d2` around the hole, and once using `d1` around a *terminating expression*. You've only used your pattern once, using `d2` around the hole. You need another iteration, around some `zero` (like `nil` in the notation for lists).

```
Notation "[ d1 , .. , d2 ]" :=
  (addition (multiply .. (addition (multiply zero ten) d1) .. ten) d2).
```

If you don't wish to introduce a zero, you can require at least two digits inside the brackets (instead of just one as above), and use that as the terminating expression. This is like the notation for pairs (in `Init/Notations.v`, also presented in the manual). You could complement this with a notation for `[d0]` with lower priority, but as this is just `d0` there isn't much point.

```
Notation "[ d0 , d1 , .. , d2 ]" :=
  (addition (multiply .. (addition (multiply d0 ten) d1) .. ten) d2).
```